# How to avoid data loss on server failure with MongoDB on a single machine?

Tags: mongodb, performance, durability, nosql

I have read that mongoDB don't write data to disk right away, it does this periodically.

Any thoughts on how to deal with this?

Comment: Have you read the MongoDB docs?  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable journaling with `--journal`.

Check out http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/03/mongodb-journaling-performance-single.html and http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair

Comment: From MongoDB v2.0, jounaling is enabled by default.

Comment: Just to clarify -- journal by default enabled in 2.0 at 64 bit machines.

Comment: And *only* in 64 bit machines :)

Answer (score 3):

Besides `--journal` that is enabled by default since MongoDB 2.0 (**only** on 64 bit machines), there is a flag that you can set when persisting data:

- `safe => false`: do not wait for a db response
- `safe => true`: wait for a db response
- `safe => num`: wait for that many servers to have the write before returning
- `fsync => true`: fsync the write to disk before returning. `fsync => true` implies `safe=>true`, but not visa versa.

If `fsync=>false` and `safe=>true` and the write could be in successfully applied to a mmapped file but not yet written to disk