# Safely Persisting to Disk

Tags: database, filesystems

A few years ago MongoDB caught some heat for having an unsafe default relating to disk persistence (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550583/how-to-avoid-data-loss-on-server-failure-with-mongodb-on-a-single-machine/7571282#7571282) for instance). What measures *must* a database implementation go through to ensure that writes to disk are safe? Is it sufficient to call `fsync()` after a write, or must other precautions be taken such as journaling or particular ways of using the disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `fsync()` would flush the dirty pages in the buffer cache to the disk. This depends on the load on your server, as having a large number of dirty pages in the cache and initiating a flush could causes the system to hung or get to an unresponsive state. However  its recommended tune some of the kernel turntables with optimal values for `vm.dirty_expire_centisecs`, `vm.dirty_background_ratio` to make sure all writes a safe and quick and not kept in the cache for a long time. Having lower values could slow average I/O speed as constantly trying to write dirty pages out will just trigger the I/O congestion code more frequently.

Alternatively,  some of the databases provide Direct I/O as a feature of the file system whereby file reads and writes go directly from the applications to the storage device, bypassing caches. Direct I/O is mostly used in applications (databases) that manage their own caches with the O_DIRECT flag.